# Problem with quoted filenames in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Let I have a batch program:

```
SET FOO=C:\temp\%1
bar.exe %FOO%
```

When I call it with double quoted file name as an argument I get these quotes in the middle; and that fact prevents other programs from working correctly:

```
> fail.bat "aa bb.jpg"
SET FOO=C:\temp\"aa bb.jpg"
> bar.exe C:\temp\"aa bb.jpg"
cannot find file
```

How to get variable containing correct value "C:\temp\aa bb.jpg"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%~1` instead, this removes the quotes from the parameter.
Then your code should look like

```
SET FOO="C:\temp\%~1"
bar.exe %FOO%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the drive letter as I have had issues with that in the past.  Also does it work if the entire path name is in quotes not just the single item with spaces?